# use a list outside my loop to concatenate a url string with some list values

Tags: python, amazon-sqs

Im getting 3 messages from sqs queue: mapper.py, reducer.py and test.txt
...and Im storing each message inside a list.

And I want to use the content of each message in my mapper, reducer and input variables(last 3 code lines).

But outside my while loop from line where i Have `print "Connecting to EMR"` Im not seeing how can I use my list of filenames for the purpose I want.

Do you see any solution for this?

In my `print item` inside for loop it shows only the first element of filenames_list.

```
conn = SQSConnection()
myqueue = conn.get_queue('myQueue')
while myqueue.count() != 0:
    filenames_list = list()
    message = myqueue.read()

    myqueue.delete_message(message)
    filename = message.get_body()

    filenames_list.append(filename)


for item in files_list: 
    print item

print "Connecting to EMR"
conn = boto.emr.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
print "Creating Streaming step"
step = StreamingStep(name='Example1',

# after myFolder/ I want to put here the content of my list relative to test.txt

mapper="s3n://myFolder/HereIWantToPutTheListContentRelatedToMapper.py",  

# after myFolder/ I want to put here the content of my list relative to reducer.py

reducer="s3n://myFolder/HereIWantToPutTheListContentRelatedToReducer.py",   

# after myFolder/ I want to put here the content of my list relative to mapper.py 
input='s3n://myFolder/HereIWantToPutTheListContentRelatedToTest.txt',  

output='s3n://myFolder/output/wordcount_output')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing files_list to an empty list at the start of each iteration of the while_loop, so perhaps you want to initialize it outside the list and append to it on each iteration of the while loop?

Comment: Thanks!! Dont know how I didnt see that. By the way, now that I have my list with mapper, reducer, and test.txt, do you know in my variables mapper, reducer and input how I can put the correct list values in each variable?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what tools are being used there, so clearly don't have any actual experience with what they expect for values.  If you're trying to get the right value from files_list into each variable, you might just want to try doing it in the while loop, or perhaps you want to use a dictionary for files_list instead of a list so you can keep track of which value goes with each key.